# Comparing the elements of a matrix to each other "column-wise" in C

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

Forgive me if the title is misleading/inappropriate.

**What I want to accomplish:** Let's say I have an *n-by-m* matrix. I wish to compare each element with the remaining elements in the same column, count the number of times the test element exceeds or equals the other elements, and store that value (no. of times) each time for further use. First, I tried to code a similar program (in C) for a 2-by-2 matrix. The code is given below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int M[2][2]={
    {4,6},
    {9,2},
    };
    int i,j,row,col;
    int arr[2][2]={0};
    int t;
    for(i=0;i<2;++i)
    {
        for(j=0;j<2;++j)
        {
            t=M[i][j];
            for(col=0;col<2;++col)
            {
                for(row=0;row<2;++row)
                {
                    if(row==i && col==j)
                        continue;
                    else if(t>=M[row][col])
                        arr[i][j]+=1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The Matrix:\n");
    for(i=0;i<2;++i){
        for(j=0;j<2;++j)
            printf("%d  ",arr[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
[0  0;0  0]
```

But, **the desired output** should be:

```
[0  1;1  0]
```

So, I have made some blunder. I think the "no. of times" values aren't getting updated properly in the 2D array `arr[2][2]`. However, I am not able to think of a way to overcome this thing at present. Please suggest how to resolve the issue.

Comment: I would expect to use three nested loops, not four.  Are you sure you need four levels?

Comment: I don't get why the last row should not be always 0, since there are no further elements in any column. If you are also including the present row, then in the last row there is always 1 element >= that element, in the same column.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sir, the last row can be non-zero as well (without considering the present row). For example, if I consider the matrix: `[5  4;8  9]`. Then the output matrix should be: `[0  0;1  1]`. That is, I need to compare each element with the remaining ones (except the test element itself) in the same column to get the value of the counter for the individual elements.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sir, without four loops, how could I store the values of the "counter" in a matrix form?

Comment: Your program outputs `1 2` / `3 0` for me (so, I do not reproduce the result you claim).  And that's what I would expect of it, since it is computing for each position how many elements at other positions *of the whole matrix* are less than or equal to the element at the selected position.

Comment: With a program using 3 nested loops, I would expect the outermost loop to select each column in turn, the middle loop would cycle through the rows in the column, and the innermost loop would scan over the remaining elements in the column, counting the number of times the current element (test element, identified by the loop indices of the outer two loops) is not smaller than the remaining elements identified by the innermost loop.  I don't see what the fourth loop could be doing.

Comment: Bottom line: you are aggregating the results of more comparisons than you claim you want.  This issue is localized to the innermost two loops.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ah yes, initially I started with three loops only, eventually, I thought since I need to store the values as a matrix so I should use four instead of three. But, now that you've pointed this out I see why four loops are superfluous. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) mentioned in a comment above, 4 nested loops are too much. You can achieve what you want using 3 nested loops:

```
size_t count_ge(const size_t nrows, const size_t ncols, int in[nrows][ncols], int out[nrows][ncols])
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < ncols; ++j) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nrows; ++i) {
            for (size_t k = 0; k < nrows; ++k) {
                if (k == i)
                    continue;
                
                if (in[i][j] >= in[j][k])
                    out[i][j] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Applying this on the same example you provided:

```
int main(void)
{
    int array[2][2] = {{4, 6}, {9, 2}};
    int counts[2][2] = {{0}};
    
    count_ge(2, 2, array, counts);
    print_array_2d(2, 2, counts);
}
```

Output:

```
0 1
1 0
```

---

The other function:

```
void print_array_2d(const size_t nrows, const size_t ncols, int array[nrows][ncols])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nrows; ++i)
        print_array_1d(ncols, array[i]);
}
```

which calls:

```
void print_array_1d(const size_t size, int array[size])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: The question says, in part, _compare each element with the remaining elements in the same column, count the number of times the test element exceeds or equals the other elements_.  I think the word 'remaining' means that your inner loop should be `for (int k = i + 1; k < nrows; k++)` rather than starting at 0.  A 2x2 matrix is a good test for an edge case (though a 1x1 matrix is the ultimate degenerate case), but not as a general demonstration of the code.  But I completely agree with using functions for the printing, etc.

Comment: @Zakk unfortunately, being new to this site, I can neither upvote a comment nor an answer. Anyways, sir, thanks for elaborating on all these things. I have two questions (which may sound lame!): 1. What does `size_t` mean starting from the return type of the function `count_ge`? 2. The way you have defined the function `print_array_2d` is unique to me. I mean, what is (are) the advantage(s) of defining it in this manner?

Comment: @Usual_Learner Now you can. And you should also check Jonathan's answer, it has great material.

Comment: @Usual_Learner Do you agree with Jonathan's comment above? Is that what you really want to achieve?

Comment: I think the condition `if(k==i) continue;` does the job!

Comment: Yesterday, I asked about the `size_t` data type. I completely forgot that such a data type does exist! I feel dumb now. Thank you for not replying to that.

Answer (score 0):

As I noted in comments:

> I would expect to use three nested loops, not four. Are you sure you need four levels?

> With a program using 3 nested loops, I would expect the outermost loop to select each column in turn, the middle loop would cycle through the rows in the column, and the innermost loop would scan over the remaining elements in the column, counting the number of times the current element (test element, identified by the loop indices of the outer two loops) is not smaller than the remaining elements identified by the innermost loop. I don't see what the fourth loop could be doing.

Your 2x2 test case is nice and small, but IMO it is too small for comfort.  There's no need to go dramatically big, but bigger than 2x2 would be good (3x3, 3x4, 4x3 would be sufficient).

As [John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger) noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73004773/comparing-the-elements-of-a-matrix-to-each-other-column-wise-in-c?noredirect=1#comment128941371_73004773), your code actually produces a different result from the one you claim:

```
1  2
3  0
```

The code below implements what I outlined in the comment about how 3 loops would work.  The code does not rely on the result matrix being initialized.  Note the use of functions to print matrices and to do the calculation.  This allows for easier testing of multiple sets of test data.  Indeed, I have a variant of the code shown that wraps the print-compute-print sequence into a function, so that the `main()` program simply defines some matrices and calls that function to do the work.

The non-standard header `matmaxfldwid.h` is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.  It provides a macro `max_field_width` that invokes inline functions to calculate the necessary width for printing all the elements of a matrix in a uniform width (so it's a "header-only" library function).  You can ignore how it works; suffice to say, it does.

My test matrices are generated by a (complex) shell script that is not currently available in my SOQ repository.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "matmaxfldwid.h"

static void dump_matrix(const char *tag, size_t rows, size_t cols, int matrix[rows][cols])
{
    printf("%s (%zux%zu):\n", tag, rows, cols);
    int fldwid = max_field_width(rows, cols, matrix);

    for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        const char *pad = "";
        for (size_t c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        {
            printf("%s%*d", pad, fldwid, matrix[r][c]);
            pad = " ";
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

static void count_matrix(size_t rows, size_t cols, int matrix[rows][cols], int result[rows][cols])
{
    for (size_t c = 0; c < cols; c++)
    {
        for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        {
            int value = matrix[r][c];
            int count = 0;
            for (size_t i = r + 1; i < rows; i++)
            {
                if (value >= matrix[i][c])
                    count++;
            }
            result[r][c] = count;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    /* Created by: gen_matrix -n N -L -99 -H +99 -r 5 -c 6 -E -w 3 -i */
    /* Random seed: 0x8E280D99 */
    int N[5][6] =
    {
        {  79, -40,  52,  26, -35,  86, },
        { -68,  13,  21, -34,  -9,  10, },
        {   7,  72,  68,  44,  45,  -3, },
        {  25,  78,  86,  81,  51, -33, },
        { -38, -89,  42,  61, -24,  69, },
    };
    enum { N_ROWS = 5, N_COLS = 6 };
    int result1[N_ROWS][N_COLS];

    dump_matrix("N", N_ROWS, N_COLS, N);
    count_matrix(N_ROWS, N_COLS, N, result1);
    dump_matrix("Result", N_ROWS, N_COLS, result1);
    putchar('\n');

    /* Created by: gen_matrix -n matrix -L -9 -H +9 -r 8 -c 6 -E -w 2 -i */
    /* Random seed: 0x00B6E0F7 */
    int matrix[8][6] =
    {
        { -3, -5,  5, -4,  7,  9, },
        {  9,  9, -9, -2,  4, -3, },
        {  2,  5, -8,  9, -7, -5, },
        {  5, -9, -5,  8,  2,  2, },
        {  5,  2, -5, -9,  4, -5, },
        {  1, -5, -3, -2,  4,  5, },
        {  8,  5,  3, -2,  1,  9, },
        {  4,  3,  2,  2,  9, -1, },
    };
    enum { MATRIX_ROWS = 8, MATRIX_COLS = 6 };
    int result3[MATRIX_ROWS][MATRIX_COLS];

    dump_matrix("Matrix", MATRIX_ROWS, MATRIX_COLS, matrix);
    count_matrix(MATRIX_ROWS, MATRIX_COLS, matrix, result3);
    dump_matrix("Result", MATRIX_ROWS, MATRIX_COLS, result3);
    putchar('\n');

    int M[2][2] =
    {
        {4, 6},
        {9, 2},
    };
    int result2[2][2];

    dump_matrix("M", 2, 2, M);
    count_matrix(2, 2, M, result2);
    dump_matrix("Result", 2, 2, result2);
    putchar('\n');

    printf("Original code:\n");
    dump_matrix("M", 2, 2, M);

    int i, j, row, col;
    int arr[2][2] = {0};
    int t;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
        {
            t = M[i][j];
            for (col = 0; col < 2; ++col)
            {
                for (row = 0; row < 2; ++row)
                {
                    if (row == i && col == j)
                        continue;
                    else if (t >= M[row][col])
                        arr[i][j] += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("The Matrix:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
            printf("%d  ", arr[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When run, it produces the output:

```
N (5x6):
 79 -40  52  26 -35  86
-68  13  21 -34  -9  10
  7  72  68  44  45  -3
 25  78  86  81  51 -33
-38 -89  42  61 -24  69
Result (5x6):
4 1 2 1 0 4
0 1 0 0 1 2
1 1 1 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0

Matrix (8x6):
-3 -5  5 -4  7  9
 9  9 -9 -2  4 -3
 2  5 -8  9 -7 -5
 5 -9 -5  8  2  2
 5  2 -5 -9  4 -5
 1 -5 -3 -2  4  5
 8  5  3 -2  1  9
 4  3  2  2  9 -1
Result (8x6):
0 2 7 1 6 7
6 6 0 3 5 2
1 5 0 5 0 1
3 0 1 4 1 2
2 1 0 0 2 0
0 0 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0

M (2x2):
4 6
9 2
Result (2x2):
0 1
0 0

Original code:
M (2x2):
4 6
9 2
The Matrix:
1  2  
3  0
```

Comment: Great answer. It has the disadvantage of using an external library. I think this is a little bit overkill for a simple task.

Comment: I won't say I understood everything. But, I enjoyed reading it. And, indeed, for my code, the output matrix is `[1 2;3 0]`. By the way, sir, for the example I used, the resultant matrix should be `[0 1;1 0]`. However, it is not so in the output that you've shown!

Comment: @Zakk — it gives me the appearance I want int printouts and will work neatly regardless of the values in the matrices.  But it's an internal library for me.  You can handle the field width in many ways, including a fixed size or no specified size.

Comment: @Usual_Learner — a lot depends on the interpretation of “the remaining elements”.   I interpreted it as “those elements lower down the column than the current element”.  If you mean “the other elements” of the column, then it's easy to adapt to that definition.  Simply change the `i` loop to run from 0 instead of `r + 1` and subtract one when assigning the result (to exclude the self-comparison).  This is a part of why the 2x2 example is barely adequate; it can't readily cover many special cases.

Comment: Got it, sir. Thanks for taking the time to write down your informative answer :)